# Stream Windows screen to DLNA TV

Tags: gratis, windows-7, streaming, dlna, wireless

I am looking for a program to allow me to stream my entire screen to my internet enabled DLNA TV. I know I can use things like [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) to stream *media*, but I want to stream my entire desktop.

Basically, I want a program that can wirelessly do something a wired HDMI connection could do.

Requirements:

- Cheap. Preferably **free**
- not *too* much **lag** - there will obviously be *some* lag, but less would be preferable!
- streams **entire screen**
- runs on Windows 7 64 bit